# How to extract field from an array returned from an API3 call

Tags: api, php

I am trying to extract a custom field from a contact record. The API returns an array of the following form:

```
Array (
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => array (
        [0] => array (
            [value 1] => 123
            [value 2] => 456
            [value 3] => 789
)))
```

Using php how can I extract value 1, 2 or 3?

**Later information**

This is the actual array

```
Array (
[0] => 0
[1] => 3
[2] => 1
[3] => 2911
[4] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [contact_id] => 2911
        [civicrm_value_aru_data_1_id] => 2586
        [custom_64] => 2014848
        [id] => 2911
```

)))

and I want to extract the value of custom_64. I am using:

```
$rugby_id = $arrayvariable[4][0][custom_64];
```

which returns nothing and I can't see where I am going wrong.

**Even later information**

I am still struggling with this issue. In an attempt to simplify things I have changed the CiviCRM API call to 'getsingle' and stored the result as follows:

```
$results = print_r($result, true);
echo $results;
```

which leads to the following:

```
Array (
[contact_id] => 2911 
[civicrm_value_aru_data_1_id] => 2586 
[custom_64] => 2014848 
[id] => 2911 
)
```

If I now try to extract the value of custom_64 using:

```
$rugby_id = $results['custom_64'];
```

The value returned is 'A'. I have researched this to death but have not found the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have given the way you would is

`$arrayvariable[2][0][value 1]` etc etc.

You can see an example here for usage from CiviCRM API v3 https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/options/#sequential

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using a different CiviCRM API3 call so that I did not need to extract a value from an array. Instead in the API Explorer I selected the entity 'contact' and action 'getvalue'. I then selected the field that I wanted and that returned a single value which I was able to use without the need to use any array processing.
In essence I walked around the issue.